# Protractor .sendKeys() and browser.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent= arguments[1];", cell, value) do not work on non-input field

Tags: protractor

I am writing automated tests with Protractor and Jasmine in TypeScript, but I cannot modify conentents of non-input fields of a table.

I have already tried using Protractor .sendKeys() and browser.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent= arguments[2];", cell, value).

Protractor .sendKeys() fails to modify it as I wish, instead it creates "0" value in the cell.

browser.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent= arguments[2];", cell, value) does change the value in the cell, at least visually. However, once I try saving the changes with pressing "Save" button on the page, the change get discarded and the value of the cell return to default.

I also tried it without .click() and .sendKeys(). Does not work.

My code:

```
    const index = await this.components.indexOf(componentName);
    const cell = await element(by.css('[row-index="'+index+'"] [col-id="value"]'));
    await cell.click();
    await cell.sendKeys(value);
    await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent= arguments[1];", cell, value);
```

the DOM with the cell in question
[image: the DOM with the cell in question]

The table itself
[image: The table itself]
I expect the values to be modified and preserved after I modify them in the table and press "Save" button

Comment: Can you show the attribute in the html that contains the value in the cell?

Comment: the snapshot corrected accordingly

Comment: what happens when you click the cell? is the DOM changed and any input shown? maybe you need to point to that field

Comment: after I click the cell, the nested span tag appears with empty text in it, if I don't type in any text, and click another cell, the span tag disappears.

Comment: Is the expected behavior for an actual user that they click the field, it becomes focused and then they can type into it?

Comment: User clicks it, types text into it and it supposed to get saved. When I do it manually, it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the following solution worked for me:

```
    const index = await this.components.indexOf(componentName);
    const cell = await element(by.css('[row-index="'+index+'"] [col-id="value"]'));
    await cell.click();
    await browser.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(value);
    await cell.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

Based on how you describe the user interaction in the comment I believe that sending the keystrokes to the browser should work for you in this instance.

```
const index = await this.components.indexOf(componentName);
const cell = await element(by.css('[row-index="'+index+'"] [col-id="value"]'));
const spanThatContainsValue = cell.element(by.tagName('span'));

//Click on the cell in order to set the focus on field
await cell.click();

//Send the keystrokes to the focused field
await browser.actions().sendKeys(value).perform();

//use delay while testing so you can manually check if entered in field
await browser.driver.sleep(10*1000);
```

Any issues let me know

Comment: hi, it cannot find the span child tag within the cell element. The span appears only after I click the cell. However, this way it also says that it cannot locate the span element:
        await cell.click();
        const spanThatContainsValue = cell.element(by.tagName('span'));
        ...

Comment: I've updated the answer, can to test out the sending keystrokes approach and let me know if there are still issues?

Comment: @DublinDev I think you need to 1st click the cell and then select the span as it appears after clicking

Comment: @JavierFromMadrid possibly yes but I assume this approach should also work as this is essentially how a real user would interact with the field. When the poster tries it out we should know more

Comment: thanks, but I found the solution in the meanwhile.
const spanThatContainsValue = cell.element(by.tagName('span')); - this line causes an error, cause span element gets added to dom only after the cell is clicked, probably. 
action chaines didn't help either